# spring hibernate auto-wiring - getting NPE on auto-wired sessionFactory - httpinvoker remoting project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, configuration, autowired

I am trying to configure and run spring + hibernate client server project (`Spring's HTTP invoker`).
I have omitted the httpinvoker configuration and web.xml , because the configuration for httpinvoker is working well . 
According to the suggestion from the answers, I removed the `TestSimple` class, and posting the stacktrace when i try to run the service from client side.

I have posted log (below) when I run `mvn tomcat:run` at server side and the stacktrace after I call the client code(posted below). I'm getting the NPE for sessionFactory. Could you please suggest some ideas?

My applicationContext.xml looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

        <!-- Database Configuration -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>/WEB-INF/config.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.url}"
        p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>
                <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.gt.cbpr.model"></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- auto wired/scan annotation based config -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gt.cbpr.server" />
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My LoginUserServiceImpl :

```
package com.gt.cbpr.server.service.impl;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.gt.cbpr.model.LoginUser;
import com.gt.cbpr.service.LoginUserService;

@Component
public class LoginUserServiceImpl implements LoginUserService {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void saveLoginUser(LoginUser user) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(sessionFactory);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(user);

    }
}
```

Client side code :

```
import com.gt.cbpr.model.LoginUser;
import com.gt.cbpr.service.LoginUserService;
import com.gt.lib.utils.BeanUtils;

public class HelloClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        LoginUserService lus = (LoginUserService) BeanUtils.getBean("loginService");
        LoginUser u  = new LoginUser();
        u.setUsername("AA");
        u.setPassword("AAAASS");
        lus.saveLoginUser(u); // I get exception here.
    }
}
```

The tomcat log :
http://pastebin.com/Xw92PJv6

The stacktrace when i run the above client code :

```
10:47:11,938 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:819 - DispatcherServlet with name 'remoting' processing POST request for [/cbpr/remoting/helloService]
10:47:11,942 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:124 - Mapping [/helloService] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter@93fd01] and 1 interceptor
10:47:11,946 DEBUG HttpInvokerServiceExporter:73 - Applying RemoteInvocation: method name 'setHello'; parameter types [com.gt.cbpr.model.HelloObject]
10:47:11,950 DEBUG RemoteInvocationTraceInterceptor:66 - Incoming HttpInvokerServiceExporter remote call: com.gt.cbpr.service.HelloService.setHello
10:47:11,950 DEBUG RemoteInvocationTraceInterceptor:72 - Finished processing of HttpInvokerServiceExporter remote call: com.gt.cbpr.service.HelloService.setHello
10:47:11,956 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:957 - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'remoting': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
10:47:11,956 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:913 - Successfully completed request
10:47:11,961 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:819 - DispatcherServlet with name 'remoting' processing POST request for [/cbpr/remoting/helloService]
10:47:11,961 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:124 - Mapping [/helloService] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter@93fd01] and 1 interceptor
10:47:11,962 DEBUG HttpInvokerServiceExporter:73 - Applying RemoteInvocation: method name 'getHello'; parameter types []
10:47:11,962 DEBUG RemoteInvocationTraceInterceptor:66 - Incoming HttpInvokerServiceExporter remote call: com.gt.cbpr.service.HelloService.getHello
10:47:11,963 DEBUG RemoteInvocationTraceInterceptor:72 - Finished processing of HttpInvokerServiceExporter remote call: com.gt.cbpr.service.HelloService.getHello
10:47:11,964 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:957 - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'remoting': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
10:47:11,965 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:913 - Successfully completed request
10:47:11,994 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:819 - DispatcherServlet with name 'remoting' processing POST request for [/cbpr/remoting/loginService]
10:47:11,995 DEBUG BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping:124 - Mapping [/loginService] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter@9036e] and 1 interceptor
10:47:11,997 DEBUG HttpInvokerServiceExporter:73 - Applying RemoteInvocation: method name 'saveLoginUser'; parameter types [com.gt.cbpr.model.LoginUser]
10:47:11,999 DEBUG RemoteInvocationTraceInterceptor:66 - Incoming HttpInvokerServiceExporter remote call: com.gt.cbpr.service.LoginUserService.saveLoginUser
null


10:47:12,009  WARN RemoteInvocationTraceInterceptor:80 - Processing of HttpInvokerServiceExporter remote call resulted in fatal exception: com.gt.cbpr.service.LoginUserService.saveLoginUser
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.gt.cbpr.server.service.impl.LoginUserServiceImpl.saveLoginUser(LoginUserServiceImpl.java:25)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationTraceInterceptor.invoke(RemoteInvocationTraceInterceptor.java:70)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy26.saveLoginUser(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocation.invoke(RemoteInvocation.java:205)
        at org.springframework.remoting.support.DefaultRemoteInvocationExecutor.invoke(DefaultRemoteInvocationExecutor.java:38)
        at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.invoke(RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.java:76)
        at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.invokeAndCreateResult(RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.java:112)
        at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter.handleRequest(HttpInvokerServiceExporter.java:117)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:49)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
10:47:12,020 DEBUG HttpInvokerServiceExporter:92 - Target method failed for RemoteInvocation: method name 'saveLoginUser'; parameter types [com.gt.cbpr.model.LoginUser]
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.gt.cbpr.server.service.impl.LoginUserServiceImpl.saveLoginUser(LoginUserServiceImpl.java:25)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationTraceInterceptor.invoke(RemoteInvocationTraceInterceptor.java:70)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
        at $Proxy26.saveLoginUser(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocation.invoke(RemoteInvocation.java:205)
        at org.springframework.remoting.support.DefaultRemoteInvocationExecutor.invoke(DefaultRemoteInvocationExecutor.java:38)
        at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.invoke(RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.java:76)
        at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.invokeAndCreateResult(RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.java:112)
        at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter.handleRequest(HttpInvokerServiceExporter.java:117)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:49)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
10:47:12,064 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:957 - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'remoting': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
10:47:12,067 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:913 - Successfully completed request
```

I could not figure out what wrong going on. Can you please help me in this?

Comment: Can you paste in the code where you are using the LoginUserServiceImpl? The test code isn't correct, I suspect your service code is similarly incorrect.

Comment: What is the actual exception's stack trace? It's already mentioned in SJuan76's answer that the test won't work.

Comment: hi, i just posted the stacktrace. please look again. I am not using the TestSimple class now. I am calling the service from client side.

Answer (score 4):

Just a guess, but you are calling `saveUser` from the constructor. I am not sure about spring, but in other CDI I have used the beans are not injected when the object is created, but after the object has been created.

For this kind of "initialization", you should use `saveUser` with `@PostConstruct` (that will execute the method after the dependencies have been injected). The method should take no parameters. And of course you should remove the method call from the constructor.

Comment: +1, clearly there is `TestSimple.<init>` in the stack. Also the OP can use constructor injection, but `@PostConstruct` is a better option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just wrote TestSimple class to demonstrate my problem. but unfortunately it also generate different error. Now I have edited the question to show my actual problem. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 3):

The logs you show are the logs of your web application. Your test is a standalone application, where the main method simply instantiate your test class using `new`. There is no way for Spring to autowire a bean that it doesn't instantiate itself. When you construct a bean using new, you're bypassing Spring completely.

Your main method needs to instantiate an application context, and to ask this context for the bean of type `TestSimple`.

The anwser of @SJUan76 is correct as well. Spring instantiates the bean , then autowire it. So in the constructor, nothing is autowired yet. It's generally a bad practice to do something other than initialization in a constructor.

Comment: Since TestSimple class is under `context:component-scan base-package="com.gt.cbpr.server"` , I thought the auto-wire should work here.

Comment: It will be, if Spring is bootstrapped some way, and if you ask Spring to create it rather than creating it yourself. If you never create a Spring application context, Spring doesn't exist in your app, the context.xml is never read, and nothing is autowired. And even if you create a Spring application context, Spring is not black magic. It can't autowire beans that it doesn't create. Remember that Spring annotations are just that: annotations. They're just metadata, but don't do anything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have now posted my actual problem. Could you please look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't pulling TestSimple out of a Spring context, so the @Autowired tag does nothing. In your main, pull the object out of a spring context instead, this will work better.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing integration tests to test the behavior of your beans inside an application container then you should consider using [Spring TestContext framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/testing.html#testcontext-framework) (it's the official way to write integration tests for Spring) - there's no magic in - normally JUnit will run Spring Test Context classes which implement JUnit Class Runner Api. So, you run JUnit, JUnit runs TestContext Framework, Test Context Framework creates application context from specified XML configuration file and runs your tests. Simple.

The unit tests are another story , there you test your beans separately by mocking their dependencies. In this part, you have to inject your the dependencies of your beans manually - there is no DI container so you have to call constructors and property setters directly from your test classes. Also that probably means that you'll have to replace your @Autowired fields with the public @Autowired property setters.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I have updated my question. Please have a look at **UPDATE:** part.

Comment: @gt_ebuddy the test won't ever work because it's outside of spring application context, please post your actual null pointer exception's stack trace that occurs in your application, not test

Comment: @gt_ebuddy Hah, btw SJuan76 already answered - even inside the application container the test won't work because the field *lus* not autowired yet into your TestSimple class during the construction of TestSimple - so you should not call SaveUser from the constructor - you can not set properties and fields of java object before the object is created. It does not matter whether you execute the constructor directly or via the reflection(as spring does), so it's impossible for spring to set *lus* value without executing the constructor first.